# Which language expresses aspect most similarly to English?

Tags: english, list-of-languages, comparative-linguistics, aspect

I suppose there are at least two ways to read this question (forgive me, I'm not a linguist, just a struggling practical language student):

1) Which languages' aspects map onto those in English most closely (semantically)?

2) Which languages express aspect most similarly to English (formally)?

Answer (score -2):

English belongs to the West Germanic family tree. There are a lot of different options about which language is the closet to English. However, Semantically Scots is the closest to English.

Moreover, English originated from Fris which is a language spoken in the northern province of the Netherlands called "Friesland". Fris is still being spoken in the Netherlands.

Furthermore, English had large influence on Latin words due to the occupation of the French in England during the middle ages.

It is hard to say which language is closest as it is a mix of Germanic, Latin, French, and even greek.

Comment: I don't see how your answer approaches *aspect*. English is very different from other Germanic languages in its handling of *aspect*.